# Alpha fade direction on Android

Tags: android, android-animation, alpha

Is it possible to change the alpha value of an ImageView along a specific direction i.e. from top to bottom or bottom to top on Android?

I am trying to animate with `imageView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(500).start();`
however this just fades the entire view out uniformly, but I'd like to do this form top to bottom instead.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How big are the pixel dimensions of the image you want to attempt this on?

Comment: Its a dynamically constructed bitmap so could vary

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not (yet) possible with the Android built in animations. You will have to create your own custom animation. 
Haven't tried, but maybe you can achieve this by using the [Transformation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Transformation.html) class, and/or overriding the [onApplyTransformation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html#applyTransformation(float,%20android.view.animation.Transformation)) method from the [AlphaAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html) class

method.

Comment: Thanks will look into this. Do you happen to have an example of something like this by any chance?